# tinymce performance - loading css multiple times

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a page with tons of tinymce enabled text areas which it is taking a huge amount of time to load. It apparently is requesting the same css file (`content.min.css`) once per textarea.

[image: so many requests!]

So is there a way to speed up a page that has this big number of tinymce areas?

I'm initializing each one independently because I'm setting each editor with an independent function.

`tinymce.init({
        theme: 'modern',
        plugins: 'link lists code textcolor',
        toolbar1: 'undo redo ...',
        menubar: false,
        forced_root_block: false,
        selector:'textarea[unique_id=' + unique_id + ']',
        setup : function(ed) {
            var change_func = function(e) {
                input.val(ed.getContent());
                debounce_func();
            }
            ed.on('keyup', change_func);
            ed.on('change', change_func);
        }
    });`

Thanks!

EDIT:
I wondered if initializing all at once would be better, so I made it to initialize all textareas with a single call to `tinymce.init` but it did not make any improvement

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standard approach to loading TinyMCE it will have to load that CSS for each editor as each one is in a separate iFrame which is (effectively) like a separate browser window.  They can't share the CSS across the iFrames.

If you use inline mode instead the CSS would be loaded once as there is only ever one instance of the editor actually invoked on the page.